# PDO - Iteratively Binding Variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a function to iteratively bind variables. This is what I have so far:

```
function prepareQuery($db, $query, $args) {
    // Returns a prepared statement
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    foreach ($args as $arg => $value) {
        $stmt->bindParam($arg, $value);
        }
    return $stmt;
    }
```

This is how I'm using it:

```
$stmt = prepareQuery($db, "SELECT * FROM `Licenses` WHERE `verCode`=:verCode", Array(":verCode" => $verCode));
$verCode = "some_string";
$stmt->execute();
while ($info = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($info);
    }
```

Though it doesn't print anything. I know the database entry exists, and the same query works from PHPMyAdmin. So, I think it's just a problem in how my function tries to create the bindings. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `execute` and pass parameters to it?

Comment: @bitWorking, I frequently wonder the same thing, because 90% of people using PDO seem to believe they need to use bindParam(). I notice that in the [documentation for PDOStatement::execute()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), the bindParam() method is described first, and the pass-array-to-execute() method is described second. I wonder if more people would learn the execute() method if it were documented first?

Comment: Perhaps you should give a value for $verCode **BEFORE** using it...

Comment: I think when you are binding the value to the placeholder $value is empty. But I'm new with PDO so I can be wrong...

Comment: @BillKarwin yes that might by true. But I also think that many people do not know `php.net` at all.

Comment: @BillKarwin I saw both methods, but I thought that using `bindParam()` would be faster. This is just an example, but in other uses, I will be calling the same query (with different values) thousands of times.

Comment: @Olvathar oh, you are right! and this issue has nothing to do with PDO at all

Comment: Thank your @YourCommonSense I was completely astonished xD

Comment: @Olvathar because it's `bindParam` and not `bindValue` it works in this way! I've tested it and the docs says: `.. the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called`

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm in big mistake but function
prepareQuery($db, $query, $args) receive no value, so bindParam functios couldn't know what's the variable used out of it's own scope.. what will bind? a null value bound to a $value instanced just for the foreach iterator? I'm going right now to read more about and make a test but it's hard to believe

Comment: @Olvathar you are right again. Issue is not connected to any PDO-related issue just because error happens *earlier* than PDO gets involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not create a function to iteratively bind variables. PDO can do it already

   ```
   function prepareQuery($db, $query, $args) {
       $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
       $stmt->execute($args);
       return $stmt;
   }
   ```
2. If it doesn't print anything, then it didn't find anything. As simple as that.
3. You don't even need this prepare query function actually. Just amend PDO very little like this

   ```
   class myPDOStatement extends PDOStatement
   {
       function execute($data = array())
       {
           parent::execute($data);
           return $this;
       }
   }

   $user = 'root';
   $pass = '';
   $dsn  = 'mysql:charset=utf8;dbname=test;host=localhost';
   $opt  = array(
       PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
       PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
       PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => TRUE,
       PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS    => array('myPDOStatement'),
   );
   $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
   ```

and you'll be able to write such a neat chain:

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM `Licenses` WHERE `verCode`=:verCode";
$code = "some_string";
$data = $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$code])->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $info) {
    print_r($info);
}
```

Comment: I know for a fact that the row exists, because I've run the query myself in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Well, although I didn't spot that silly mistake that causing the error, the code I wrote is proof against it

Comment: shouldn't it be `parent::execute($data);` ?

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you. I cut it from the larger code which actually loops over data and forgot to put $data back